# How to use forEach and push function to update an array of object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have been playing a lot with react native lately an now I am trying to draw a polygon on map with a lot of coordinates.

My JSON (something like this)

```
{ 
    "routeGeoJSON":
    {
        "features":
        [
            "geometry":
            {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [ 122, 12 ], [ 211, 19 ], ... //[ lon, lat ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want to push the value of coordinates to a new array.

My code so far

```
//import function

class RouteScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let polygon = [];

        let routePolygon = this.props.routes.data.routeGeoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];

        let obj = {};
        obj.latitude = routePolygon.forEach((element) => {
            polygon.push(element[1]);
        });
        obj.longitude = routePolygon.forEach((element) => {
            polygon.push(element[0]);
        });

        this.state = { polygon };

render() {
    const { polygon } = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView 
                provider={this.props.provider}
                style={styles.map}
                zoomEnabled
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: this.props.routes.data.routeGeoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][1],
                    longitude: this.props.routes.data.routeGeoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0],
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
            >
                <MapView.Polygon
                    coordinates={polygon}
                    fillColor="rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5)"
                    strokeColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                />

            // some code
            </MapView>
            // some code...
```

I want to fetch the coordinates from the JSON and push it to the `polygon` array so it will dynamically become like this

```
polygon: [
            {
                latitude: 12,
                longitude: 122
            },
            {....}, {...}....
          ]
```

But this resulting in `error while updating property 'coordinates' of a view managed by: AIRMapPolygon` `null` `expected Map, got a double`

What did I missed here? Is this the correct way to use `forEach` with `push`?

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: `foreach` is small case not `forEach`

Comment: it gave me `typeerror: undefined is not a function(evaluating 'routePolygon.foreach(function(element){ polygon.push(element[1])})`

Comment: the value of routePolygon is not present. It's undefined. Where r u getting it's value. is it async process?

Comment: ops sorry i thought its jQuery. okay let me see.

Comment: If you're iterating over the first element of coordinates array which is an array too if you do element[1] it will return undefined. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @Manish it is from request through axios. I don't really understand the `async` that you mentioned but if I directly set `polygon: { latitude: this.props.data...., longitude: this.props.data....}, { latitude:..., longitude:...}` , it has no problem

Comment: @sigfried any suggestion for it?

Comment: Check the answer below from @Christian Santos, also if you're using axios, yes it gets the values async, so you need to wait for axios to return the values. Let me know and I will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for appending objects to `polygon` is incorrect. What you want to do is iterate over every value in `routePolygon` and push a new object with two fields (`latitude` and `longitude`) into your `polygon` like so:

```
routePolygon.forEach((element) => {

    polygon.push({

        latitude: element[1],
        longitude: element[0]
    });
});
```

With this in mind, you don't need to create the `obj` variable that you currently have in your code. Instead, you create new objects inside of the `forEach` using the Object Literal syntax (`{}`) when you push these new objects into `polygon`.

**Edit:** I'll provide an example to show you what I mean. Run the snippet below:

```js
let routePolygon = [ [10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60] ];

let polygon = [];

routePolygon.forEach((element) => {

    polygon.push({

        latitude: element[1],
        longitude: element[0]
    });
});

console.log(polygon);
```

Comment: I did not know that I can create `obj` variable directly inside `forEach`. Thank you for your answer. This helps me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the initial JSON has **SintaxError**

```
{ 
    "routeGeoJSON":
    {
        "features":
        [
            //{ //expected
            "geometry":
            {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [ 122, 12 ], [ 211, 19 ], ... //[ lon, lat ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
          //} //closing 
        ]
    }
}
```

After fixing syntax you can use `.map` function. Something like this.

```js
let data = {
  "routeGeoJSON": {
    "features": [{
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [122, 12],
            [211, 19] //, ... //[ lon, lat ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
};
let poligon = data.routeGeoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
  .map(el => {
    return {
      longitude: el[0],
      latitude: el[1]
    };
  });
  console.log(poligon);
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It must be my mistake when typing the question. Nevertheless, your solution with `map` might be useful to me in future.

Answer (score 0):

Looking forward to what I know will help you

```html
var MyJSON = ;//You JSON
var result = [];
MyJSON.routeGeoJSON.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0].forEach(function(item, index){
  var obj = {
    latitude: item[0],
    longitude: item[1]
  };
  result.push(obj);
})
//This you can this result;
```

Comment: It would help to explain your solution :)